# A "big" crime or what?

Tags: word-usage, word-request, adjectives

I was wondering what is the most natural adjective to amplify the magnitude of a crime in the following example:

> - There is no freedom of speech and press in that country. If you protest against the regime, it will be considered as a **big** crime and will be followed by harsh penalties including flogging, torturing and even imprisonment.

Google shows [only one result](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22will+be+considered+as+a+big+crime%22&oq=%22will+be+considered+as+a+big+crime%22&aqs=chrome..69i57.5587j0j4&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) when I search the following sentence which seems to be written by a non-native.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Several options:  "Serious" or "major".  In the US, crimes are divided into "felony" and "misdemeanor" (but these are technical legal terms, not a matter of opinion)

Answer (score 2):

[Wildcard searches on GNgram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=a%20%2A%20crime%2C%20a%20big%20crime&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t2%3B%2Ca%20%2A%20crime%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Ba%20capital%20crime%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Ba%20great%20crime%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Ba%20high%20crime%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Ba%20serious%20crime%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Ba%20heinous%20crime%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Ba%20new%20crime%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Ba%20greater%20crime%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Ba%20particular%20crime%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Ba%20federal%20crime%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Ba%20political%20crime%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ca%20big%20crime%3B%2Cc0#t2%3B%2Ca%20*%20crime%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Ba%20capital%20crime%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Ba%20great%20crime%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Ba%20high%20crime%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Ba%20serious%20crime%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Ba%20heinous%20crime%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Ba%20new%20crime%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Ba%20greater%20crime%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Ba%20particular%20crime%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Ba%20federal%20crime%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Ba%20political%20crime%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ca%20big%20crime%3B%2Cc0) can be useful for that:

[image]

As you can see, you are right, ***big*** is not preferred when describing a crime, especially in a formal context. Its formal equivalent is ***great***.

PS: It is always helpful to state where you found the sentence and provide a link if available.